# Laravel сохранение в БД с подстановкой id пользователя

Tags: php, laravel

Указано в уроках, что чтобы автоматически подставить к полученным из формы данным id текущего пользователя, можно сделать так, как приведено ниже.

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $article = new Article($request->all());
    Auth::user()->articles()->save($article);

    return redirect('articles');
}
```

Однако получаю ошибку

> Class 'Article' not found

При том, что связь установлена в модели User

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Article');
}
```

Версия laravel 5.6.11

Comment: попробуйте в файле `ArticlesController.php` под объявлением пространства имён `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` дописать импортирование класса Article: `use App\Article;`

Comment: @Эдуард Это написано. Я прохожу эти курсы. Проблема возникла  на 15 уроке примерно на 14 минуте - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u7VHIT7D7zU&index=15&list=PLl_kpL5cwH6LLuvd_xXOplXejM7shFhme Там более сарая версия ларавел. Немного другая структура папок. Тем не менее всё работало до этого момента, получалось разобраться. Могу выложить на gist код, если нужно

Comment: `Это написано` - уверены, что именно это написано? К примеру, в [15-ом уроке](https://laravel.ru/posts/456) поиском по странице директива `use App\Article;` не найдена.

Comment: На счёт версий - у меня 5.4.*, и тоже бывали не соответствия с классами - спасало их ручное импортирование.

Comment: @Эдуард Уверен - я сам дописал пару уроков назад по привычке. Вот - https://gist.github.com/n-osennij/b53a9294a16183b71c5a0a25c621380f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже, что ошибка у вас в модели User. Нужно вместо:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Article');
}
```

Записать так:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
}
```

Comment: Действительно - проблема была в этом. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой (в laravel 5.5), сутки убил на решение.
В итоге помогло обновление загрузчика

`composer dump-autoload --optimize`

Вот так проблема решена была с совсем неожиданной стороны..

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но это не помогло. Решение выше

Comment: Но это решило другую мою проблему, о которой тут речь не шла) Спасибо)